# Disable receiving touches from parent view on subview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer

I have a `UIView` `parentView` which implements a `UITapGuestureRecognizer` and does something when tapped. `parentView` has a sub view called `childView` which also implements a `UITapGuestureRecognizer` and does something when tapped.

There is an instance when I have to turn off the `childViews` `UITapGestureRecognizer` during an animation for a slight moment, and I noticed when it is turned off and I tap `childView`, the tap gets intercepted by `parentView`. Also, I have a toolbar attached to the top of this view that doesn't have any gesture recognizer attached to it, and it's touches get passed parentView (the buttons will barely work). I'm wondering is it possible to disable this without having a reference to the parents UITapGestureRecognizer?

I've tried using the `exclusiveTouches` property of `UIView` set to yes and it doesn't work. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In the parent gesture recognizers, implement the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`, and implement the following method:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch 
{
    if ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[ClassThatYouWantTouchesBlocked class]]) 
    {
        return NO;
    }
    else 
    {
        return YES; 
    }
}
```

Replace `ClassThatYouWantTouchesBlocked` with the class that you want its touches to be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

What if **never turn off** the ChildView's tap gesture recognizer? if it is animating return from the child's tap gesture method without doing anything.

If it is an **imageView** than **isAnimating** property might come in use.

Comment: Valid answer - I will upvote.  People who downvote without explanation are a blight to stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Appreciate the effort Warif but downvoted because it isn't answering the question, it's trying to change the problem statement.  And @Cthutu , I'd say you're more of a blight to stackoverflow.com for spite upvoting because I didn't explain.

Comment: Nope I upvoted because I thought it was a valid answer, not out of spite.  I thought that was clear from "Valid answer" in my comment.  Warif was thinking out of the box and that's commendable.  You don't deserve to have your questions answered.

Comment: **@CoDEFRo** I think people just don't answer for "voting". They want to gather info and have the feelings of helping others. You never said why you are doing this in your question ***"I have to turn off the childViews UITapGestureRecognizer."*** I was suggesting what if keep the child tapGesture **ON**. So the gestures don't travel though the childView.

Comment: **@Cthutu** Thank you so much. Different people think differently. But I strongly agree with you that people should have an explanation.

Comment: WarifAkhandRishi - Usually if you want to gather info it's better said in the comments section. As far as turning the childViews tapGestureRecognizer off, sorry if it wasn't obvious, but that's something that isn't an option, I need to have it that way. But still I feel that's an alteration to the problem statement, and not an answer. Anyway, agree to disagree, and appreciate you not getting over emotional and resorting to name calling, unlike some other people @Cthutu

Comment: I was describing a group of people who downvote without explanation.  It's unhelpful, demoralising and lessens the usefulness of SO. However, it was you that first got personal.  You should have explained that turning off the childViews tapGestureRecognizer was not an option in the comments instead of anonymously downvoting.

Answer (score 1):

Add gesture recognizer to blocker child.

```
self.blockerView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer())
```